# WSO2 APIM: Admin application generate Unexpected EOF in prolog in BPS when login

Tags: wso2, admin, wso2-api-manager, wso2-business-process

We are configuring WSO2 API manager (version 2.1.0) for using Application Creation workflow.

For this, we have configured a BPS node (version 3.6.0), as described in 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Adding+an+Application+Creation+Workflow
also, we have done the adjustments described in
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+Workflows+in+a+Cluster
that are required because we are using 2 different nodes, with different names.

Now, the Application Creation process / workflow seems to work fine, and Approval and Rejections are received and processed.

But we have still an error. 
When we log in the admin application (https://apimanager.example.com:9443/admin), we see an error in the BPS node.

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-06-18 10:36:20,508]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil} -  OMException in getSOAPBuilder {org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil}
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
```

We see this error before doing anything, and in any case (with no task, with pending tasks and no pending tasks)

It's clear that admin application is calling a WebService in login moment, with wrong content, but we don't know how to debug it. How can we know which service is called in BPS node?

Any suggestions will be welcome.

Below, our script to install configure the workflow, and the workflow-extensions we are using

=========== Auto configuration script ==============

```
CMD_XMLSTARLET=xmlstarlet
CMD_JQ=jq
# configureWorkflow
# Configure workflows por human based approval processes
# Reference:
#       Adding an Application Creation Workflow
#       https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Adding+an+Application+Creation+Workflow
#   Adding an Application registration (generate keys) workflow
#   https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Adding+an+Application+Registration+Workflow
#       Cluster configuration (change the host names)
#   https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+Workflows+in+a+Cluster
function configureWorkflow()
{
    if [ -z $1 ] || [ -z $2 ]
    then
        echo "Indicate manager node and bps node. E.g. configureWorkflow APIM APIB" 1>&2
        exit 1
    else
        # Namespaces 
        # Default namespace for humantask.xml
        local nsh=http://wso2.org/humantask/schema/server/config
        # Default namespace for b4p-coordination-config.xml
        local nsb=http://wso2.org/bps/b4p/coordination/config
        local svns=http://org.wso2.securevault/configuration
        # WebServices   
        local wsa=http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing
        local wsdl=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/
        local soap=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/
        local soap12=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/
        # Synapse
        local nss=http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse

        # Configure workflow node
        su -c "$CMD_XMLSTARLET ed -L -N x=$nsh -u //x:HumanTaskCoordination/x:TaskCoordinationEnabled -v true $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$2]}/repository/conf/humantask.xml" $WSO2_USER_NAME
        su -c "$CMD_XMLSTARLET ed -L -N x=$nsb -u //x:TaskCoordinationEnabled -v true $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$2]}/repository/conf/b4p-coordination-config.xml" $WSO2_USER_NAME

        # Configure the workflows services (launch)
        su -c "$CMD_XMLSTARLET ed -L -N wsa=$wsa -u //wsa:EndpointReference/wsa:Address -v http://${NODE_HOST[$2]}:${NODE_PORT_HTTP_SERVLET[$2]}/services/ApplicationService $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$1]}/business-processes/epr/ApplicationService.epr" $WSO2_USER_NAME
        su -c "$CMD_XMLSTARLET ed -L -N wsa=$wsa -u //wsa:EndpointReference/wsa:Metadata/authorization-password -v $WSO2_ADMIN_PASS $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$1]}/business-processes/epr/ApplicationService.epr" $WSO2_USER_NAME

        # Configure the workflows services (callbacks)
        su -c "$CMD_XMLSTARLET ed -L -N wsa=$wsa -u //wsa:EndpointReference/wsa:Address -v https://${NODE_HOST[$1]}:${NODE_PORT_HTTPS_NIOPT[$1]}/services/WorkflowCallbackService $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$1]}/business-processes/epr/ApplicationCallbackService.epr" $WSO2_USER_NAME
        su -c "$CMD_XMLSTARLET ed -L -N wsa=$wsa -u //wsa:EndpointReference/wsa:Metadata/authorization-password -v $WSO2_ADMIN_PASS $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$1]}/business-processes/epr/ApplicationCallbackService.epr" $WSO2_USER_NAME

        # Copy configured workflows from APIM to BPS
        su -c "cp -r $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$1]}/business-processes/epr  $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$2]}/repository/conf/" $WSO2_USER_NAME

        # https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Configuring+Workflows+in+a+Cluster        

        # Install BPEL Processes
        su -c "mkdir $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$2]}/repository/deployment/server/bpel" $WSO2_USER_NAME
        su -c "cp $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$1]}/business-processes/application-creation/BPEL/ApplicationApprovalWorkFlowProcess_1.0.0.zip $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$2]}/repository/deployment/server/bpel" $WSO2_USER_NAME
        su -c "cp $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$1]}/business-processes/application-registration/BPEL/ApplicationRegistrationWorkflowProcess_1.0.0.zip $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$2]}/repository/deployment/server/bpel" $WSO2_USER_NAME
        su -c "cp $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$1]}/business-processes/user-signup/BPEL/UserSignupApprovalProcess_1.0.0.zip $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$2]}/repository/deployment/server/bpel/." $WSO2_USER_NAME
        su -c "cp $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$1]}/business-processes/subscription-creation/BPEL/SubscriptionApprovalWorkFlowProcess_1.0.0.zip $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$2]}/repository/deployment/server/bpel" $WSO2_USER_NAME
        # Install Human task processes
        su -c "mkdir $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$2]}/repository/deployment/server/humantasks" $WSO2_USER_NAME
        su -c "cp $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$1]}/business-processes/application-creation/HumanTask/ApplicationsApprovalTask-1.0.0.zip $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$2]}/repository/deployment/server/humantasks" $WSO2_USER_NAME
        su -c "cp $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$1]}/business-processes/application-registration/HumanTask/ApplicationRegistrationTask-1.0.0.zip $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$2]}/repository/deployment/server/humantasks" $WSO2_USER_NAME
        su -c "cp $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$1]}/business-processes/user-signup/HumanTask/UserApprovalTask-1.0.0.zip $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$2]}/repository/deployment/server/humantasks" $WSO2_USER_NAME
        su -c "cp $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$1]}/business-processes/subscription-creation/HumanTask/SubscriptionsApprovalTask-1.0.0.zip $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$2]}/repository/deployment/server/humantasks" $WSO2_USER_NAME

        # Configure API Manager node
        file=$WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$1]}/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/admin/site/conf/site.json
        # NOTICE: The site file is wrong, and cannot be parsed. Solve with a sed replace
        wrongLine="\\\"https://<BPSHost>:<BPSPort>/services/\\\","
        rightLine="\\\"https://<BPSHost>:<BPSPort>/services/\\\""
        su -c "sed -i.bak 's=$wrongLine=$rightLine=' $file" $WSO2_USER_NAME
        # Remove all javascript style comment lines (now allowed in jq)
        su -c "sed -i 's=^[[:blank:]]*//.*$==g' $file" $WSO2_USER_NAME
        # Worflow endpoint
        su -c "$CMD_JQ '.workflows.workFlowServerURL = \"${NODE_URL_SERVICES[$2]}\"' $file > $TMPDIR/tmp.$$.site.json && mv $TMPDIR/tmp.$$.site.json $file" $WSO2_USER_NAME
        # Callback proxy endpoints
        local jaguri="${NODE_URL_HTTPS_SERVLET[$1]}/store/site/blocks/workflow/workflow-listener/ajax/workflow-listener.jag"
        local soaphttps="${NODE_URL_HTTPS_NIOPT[$1]}/services/WorkflowCallbackService.WorkflowCallbackServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint/"
        local soaphttp="${NODE_URL_HTTP_NIOPT[$1]}/services/WorkflowCallbackService.WorkflowCallbackServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint/"
        local soap12https="${NODE_URL_HTTPS_NIOPT[$1]}/services/WorkflowCallbackService.WorkflowCallbackServiceHttpsSoap12Endpoint/"
        local soap12http="${NODE_URL_HTTP_NIOPT[$1]}/services/WorkflowCallbackService.WorkflowCallbackServiceHttpsSoap12Endpoint/"
        su -c "$CMD_XMLSTARLET ed -L -N nss=$nss -u \"//nss:proxy/nss:target/nss:inSequence/nss:send/nss:endpoint/nss:address/@uri\" -v $jaguri $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$1]}/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/proxy-services/WorkflowCallbackService.xml" $WSO2_USER_NAME
        su -c "$CMD_XMLSTARLET ed -L -N nss=$nss -N wsdl=$wsdl -N soap=$soap -u \"//nss:proxy/nss:publishWSDL/wsdl:definitions/wsdl:service/wsdl:port[@name='WorkflowCallbackServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint']/soap:address/@location\" -v $soaphttps $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$1]}/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/proxy-services/WorkflowCallbackService.xml" $WSO2_USER_NAME
        su -c "$CMD_XMLSTARLET ed -L -N nss=$nss -N wsdl=$wsdl -N soap=$soap -u \"//nss:proxy/nss:publishWSDL/wsdl:definitions/wsdl:service/wsdl:port[@name='WorkflowCallbackServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint']/soap:address/@location\" -v $soaphttp $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$1]}/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/proxy-services/WorkflowCallbackService.xml" $WSO2_USER_NAME
        su -c "$CMD_XMLSTARLET ed -L -N nss=$nss -N wsdl=$wsdl -N soap12=$soap12 -u \"//nss:proxy/nss:publishWSDL/wsdl:definitions/wsdl:service/wsdl:port[@name='WorkflowCallbackServiceHttpsSoap12Endpoint']/soap12:address/@location\" -v $soap12https $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$1]}/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/proxy-services/WorkflowCallbackService.xml" $WSO2_USER_NAME
        su -c "$CMD_XMLSTARLET ed -L -N nss=$nss -N wsdl=$wsdl -N soap12=$soap12 -u \"//nss:proxy/nss:publishWSDL/wsdl:definitions/wsdl:service/wsdl:port[@name='WorkflowCallbackServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint']/soap12:address/@location\" -v $soap12http $WSO2_PATH/${NODE_NAME[$1]}/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/proxy-services/WorkflowCallbackService.xml" $WSO2_USER_NAME

    fi
}
```

============= workflow-extensions.xml ================

```
<WorkFlowExtensions>
    <ApplicationCreation executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationCreationWSWorkflowExecutor">
         <Property name="serviceEndpoint">http://apibps.example.com:9765/services/ApplicationApprovalWorkFlowProcess/</Property>
         <Property name="username">admin</Property>
         <Property name="password">xxxxx</Property>
         <Property name="callbackURL">https://apimanager.example.com:8243/services/WorkflowCallbackService</Property>
    </ApplicationCreation>
    <ProductionApplicationRegistration executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationWSWorkflowExecutor">
        <Property name="serviceEndpoint">http://apibps.example.com:9765/services/ApplicationRegistrationWorkFlowProcess/</Property>
        <Property name="username">admin</Property>
        <Property name="password">xxxxx</Property>
        <Property name="callbackURL">https://apimanager.example.com:8243/services/WorkflowCallbackService</Property>
    </ProductionApplicationRegistration>
    <SandboxApplicationRegistration executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationWSWorkflowExecutor">
        <Property name="serviceEndpoint">http://apibps.example.com:9765/services/ApplicationRegistrationWorkFlowProcess/</Property>
        <Property name="username">admin</Property>
        <Property name="password">xxxxx</Property>
        <Property name="callbackURL">https://apimanager.example.com:8243/services/WorkflowCallbackService</Property>
    </SandboxApplicationRegistration>

    <SubscriptionCreation executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.SubscriptionCreationWSWorkflowExecutor">
         <Property name="serviceEndpoint">http://apibps.example.com:9765/services/SubscriptionApprovalWorkFlowProcess/</Property>
         <Property name="username">admin</Property>
         <Property name="password">xxxxx</Property>
         <Property name="callbackURL">https://apimanager.example.com:8243/services/WorkflowCallbackService</Property>
    </SubscriptionCreation>

    <UserSignUp executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.UserSignUpWSWorkflowExecutor">
         <Property name="serviceEndpoint">http://apibps.example.com:9765/services/UserSignupProcess/</Property>
         <Property name="username">admin</Property>
         <Property name="password">xxxxx</Property>
         <Property name="callbackURL">https://apimanager.example.com:8243/services/WorkflowCallbackService</Property>
    </UserSignUp>

    <!--
    ***NOTE:***
        Users of deletion workflows are expected to implement their own deletion workflow executors and services.
        By default API Manager only implements the core functionalities required to support deletion workflows and
        simple deletion workflow executors. Default WS deletion workflow implementations are not available with the
        distribution.
    -->

    <SubscriptionDeletion executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.SubscriptionDeletionSimpleWorkflowExecutor"/>
    <!--SubscriptionDeletion executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.SubscriptionDeletionSimpleWorkflowExecutor">
         <Property name="serviceEndpoint">http://localhost:9765/services/SubscriptionApprovalWorkFlowProcess/</Property>
         <Property name="username">admin</Property>
         <Property name="password">xxxxx</Property>
         <Property name="callbackURL">https://localhost:8243/services/WorkflowCallbackService</Property>
    </SubscriptionDeletion -->
    <ApplicationDeletion executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationDeletionSimpleWorkflowExecutor"/>
    <!--ApplicationDeletion executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationDeletionSimpleWorkflowExecutor">
         <Property name="serviceEndpoint">http://localhost:9765/services/ApplicationApprovalWorkFlowProcess/</Property>
         <Property name="username">admin</Property>
         <Property name="password">xxxxx</Property>
         <Property name="callbackURL">https://localhost:8243/services/WorkflowCallbackService</Property>
    </ApplicationDeletion-->

    <!-- Publisher related workflows -->
    <APIStateChange executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.APIStateChangeSimpleWorkflowExecutor" />
    <!-- <APIStateChange executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.APIStateChangeWSWorkflowExecutor">
        <Property name="processDefinitionKey">APIStateChangeApprovalProcess</Property>
        <Property name="stateList">Created:Publish,Published:Block</Property>        
    </APIStateChange>-->



</WorkFlowExtensions>
```

Comment: We are having the same issue when using Subscription Approval Workflow using BPS and API Manager. We do not know how to solve it. Anyway, this error does not seem to block the workflow.

Comment: Thanks! We cannot get the Application Registration workflow. Could you give us a hand? (check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50926457/wso2-apim-application-registration-urnapprove-action-not-found)