# WSO2 APIM Application Registration urn:approve action not found

Tags: wso2, registration, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-business-process

**UPDATE:** We have reproduced the same problem connecting to EI 6.1.1 business process module

We are trying to implement a application registration (generation of key) for API manager (version 2.1.0), using BPS (version 3.6.0).

For this, we are following the instructions in 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Adding+an+Application+Registration+Workflow

We have also corrected a typo in the content of the package, as provide by the
https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/pull/2730/files#diff-737be153055f194110665b96252dcebe

The previous workflow (ApplicationCreation) works fine, but this, when we click in "GenerateKeys" in store, fails with error in BPS, saying that the action urn:approve is invalid

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-06-20 21:11:32,909] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.messagetrace} -  Message received: ApplicationRegistrationWorkFlowProcess.{http://workflow.application.apimgt.carbon.wso2.org}initiate {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.messagetrace}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-06-20 21:11:33,824]  WARN {org.apache.axis2.addressing.AddressingFaultsHelper} -  triggerActionNotSupportedFault: messageContext: [MessageContext: logID=11ff1a7f886692cdddf6394b6d5e88da06b8bac0e1095ec3] problemAction: urn:approve {org.apache.axis2.addressing.AddressingFaultsHelper}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-06-20 21:11:33,830] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine} -  The [action] cannot be processed at the receiver. {org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The [action] cannot be processed at the receiver.
```

We have checked, in BPS carbon console, that the service ApplicationRegistrationWorkFlowProcess is deployed, and the WSDL 1.1 endpoint is deployed with soapAction=urn:approve.

The endpoint in API Manager (store), the workflow-extensions in registry `/_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/workflow-extensions.xml` are modified as described to

```
<SandboxApplicationRegistration executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationWSWorkflowExecutor">
    <Property name="serviceEndpoint">http://apibps.example.com:9765/services/ApplicationRegistrationWorkFlowProcess/</Property>
    <Property name="username">admin</Property>
    <Property name="password">admin</Property>
    <Property name="callbackURL">https://apimanager.example.com:8243/services/WorkflowCallbackService</Property>
</SandboxApplicationRegistration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the same with APIM 2.2.0 and BPS 3.6.0 and EI 6.2.0. It worked fine. Can you change the port in callbackURL of SandboxApplicationRegistration in workflow-extensions.xml to 8248 and retry?

Comment: I have tested with EI 6.1.1 with the same failure. Also, changed the port to 8248, with no change (the problem happens before callback, when the APIM try to start the BPEL process).

Comment: Solved! It was my fault. When edited the RegistrationService.epr, the address was wrong